# Finding largest indices of non-zero elements along each axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array. I'd like to find the largest `x`, `y` and `z` co-ordinates of non-zero element elements along each of the three axes of the array. How can I do that?

So for the example below x=1, y=2, z=1

```
array([[[1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the indices of non-zero elements with [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) and stack them up in columns with [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and finally find the `max` along the columns with [`.max(0)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html). The implementation would look something like this -

```
np.column_stack((np.nonzero(A))).max(0)
```

Looks like there is a built-in function [`np.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) for getting indices of all non-zero elements stacked in a `2D` array. Thus, you can simply do -

```
np.argwhere(A).max(0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [50]: A
Out[50]: 
array([[[1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])

In [51]: np.column_stack((np.nonzero(A))).max(0)
Out[51]: array([1, 2, 1])

In [52]: np.argwhere(A).max(0)
Out[52]: array([1, 2, 1])
```

Comment: `argwhere` is just `np.nonzero(A).T`, the nonzero indices rearranged.

Answer (score 0):

Done using [`numpy.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero)

```
>>> tuple(coords.max() for coords in numpy.nonzero(A))
(1, 2, 1)
```